# UML sequence diagram inner class representation

Tags: java, uml

I would like to know how to represent inner class in UML sequence diagram? Suppose i am making a call from class A inside method a1 to method c1 on Inner class C of class B. Something like in below pseudocode

```
class A{
  method a1(){
    B.C.c1();
  }
}

class B{
   static class C{
     static method c1(){
      // do something
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UML does not have standard notation for inner classes, that's just Java stuff. I would suggest to omit the fact that there's some inner class or just put some note on parent class if it's really important...

Answer (score 0):

I do not have it installed to provide a screenshot but you could try [eclipsediver](http://eclipsediver.wordpress.com/) to generate sequence diagrams.